# Como alterar uma classe css no componente pai ao clicar em um botão no componente filho?

Tags: angular, angular-6

Sou novo em desenvolvimento de projetos com Angular. Preciso, por favor, de uma grande ajuda.

Gostaria que uma classe `css` fosse alterada em uma `<div></div>` inserida no componente pai e quando um botão fosse clicado no componente filho as classes "sucess" e "danger" se alternassem (toggle).

Segue exemplo abaixo:

**father.component.html**

```html
<app-child></app-child>
<div [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'"></div>
```

**father.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-father',
  templateUrl: './father.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./father.component.scss'],
})
export class FatherComponent implements OnInit {

  status: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="clickEvent()">Mudar classe css no componente pai</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  status: boolean = false;
    clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: **@Input()** passa valores do componente pai para componentes filhos, já o contrário que é passar valores do componente filho para o pai vc usa **@Output()** junto com **EventEmiter()**, isso é básico no Angular.

Comment: Sim esse conceito eu conheço e sei que é básico, estava tendo problema com a sintaxe por não ter experiência com o angular, mas já resolvi, já fiz funcionar de forma correta.

Comment: Boa, isso aí man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue minha resposta:

**father.component.html**

```html
<app-child (myEvent)="receiveEvent($event)"></app-child>
<div [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'"></div>
```

**father.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-father',
  templateUrl: './father.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./father.component.scss'],
})
export class FatherComponent implements OnInit {

  status: boolean = false;
  
  receiveEvent($event) {
    this.status = $event
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="clickEvent()">Mudar classe css no componente pai</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  status: boolean = false;
  
  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();
  
  clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;
    this.myEvent.emit(this.status)
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Deveria ter um output do father status para o child, se não o father component fica depender do child para seu template, cuidado com a comunicação entre components..

Comment: Esta aplicação já está pronta, essa é a melhor forma para não ter que fazer maiores alterações nos componentes, o código acima é uma parte bem pequena da aplicação, por isso negativar a resposta não faz sentido sem conhecer a dimensão do projeto.